# How to replace all hashtags using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace all the hashtags in a tweet body using regex in java.

Firstly I used this regex `#\\w+|\\s#\\w+` but this does not work with tweets contains Arabic characters so I moved to this one

```
#[\\x{0021}-\\x{007E}\\x{060C}-\\x{06DC}^\\s]+
```

which simply match any character between the two ranges `u0021 to u007E` and `u060C to u06DC`.

The second regex works fine but for a string like this "#شو_تعلمت_من_المدرسه ولاشي" it causes the whole string to be replaced.

What is the problem with that expression? 
Is there any better regex rather than this ?

Comment: Can you give an example for the input (or a few) and a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just start at a hash and stop at a whitespace?

```
#[^\\s]*
```